# Why does this keep happening to the volume?

Tags: windows-7, audio

Basically this sums up what's happening to my PC:

[image]

The sound never 'reaches' 100% even though the 'limit' is at 100%. The programs that are producing the sounds/music are all at 100%, for example: the volume within VLC/WMP is at 100% when playing a song, yet this still happens.

I'm using the onboard Realtek sound on my motherboard (Asus Maximus VI Hero).

Other specs (if relevant):

-Winows 7 Ult 64bit

-Current sound drivers downloaded from the Asus support website: Realtek Version 6.0.1.7218

-Intel 4770K

-Nvidia GTX780Ti

-8GB DDR3 RAM

-2x WD Black 1TB

-1x Corsair Force 128GB SSD

-Speakers: Corsair SP2500

I've already tried removing the Asus (Realtek) drivers and using the default windows driver as well as completely removing it and re-installing it. Neither fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Check those too:
http://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/288802-realtek-hd-low-volume-fix.html

Rog forum, problem related but no fix
http://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?47944-Asus-Maximus-VI-Hero-Audio-Drivers/page2

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.